# How to get row with condition for different keys

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have table wp_postmeta like:

```
meta_id  post_id    meta_key    meta_value
--------------------------------------------
4175     1347       name        Dubovka
4176     1347       type        agro
4177     1347       region      1
4181     1348       name        Victoria
4181     1348       type        hotel
4181     1348       region      2
```

How to get unique post id, if I know the values of name, type, region?
It requires using JOIN in query.

Comment: Use the `DISTINCT` SQL operator

Answer (score 2):

This will do it:

```
SELECT post_id FROM wp_postmeta
GROUP BY post_id
HAVING SUM(
  (meta_key = 'name' AND meta_value = 'Dubovka') +
  (meta_key = 'type' AND meta_value = 'agro') +
  (meta_key = 'region' AND meta_value = '1')
) = 3
```

Output:

```
| POST_ID |
|---------|
|    1347 |
```

Fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c1b55/1).

Take into account that each condition you want to match between brackets means a unit you will have to increase the `SUM` comparison. In this case, 3 conditions means I compare the `SUM` against 3.

Comment: No need to thank. That's what accepting answers is there for :)